# SELECT Statement in C# Return If Null (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, select, null

Select statement only returns technician names that are not null. As technicians are not assigned to open tickets yet, I need this to return all product codes regardless of the tech name being filled or null.

```
string selectStatement =
            "SELECT ProductCode, DateOpened, Customers.Name AS CustName, " + 
            "Technicians.Name as TechName, Title, DateClosed " +
            "FROM Incidents " +
            "JOIN Customers ON Incidents.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID " +
            "JOIN Technicians ON Incidents.TechID = Technicians.TechID " +
            "WHERE DateClosed IS NULL " +
            "ORDER BY DateOpened";
```

Comment: [Visual representation of Join](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: If you use `JOIN` you actually use `INNER JOIN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this code

```
"JOIN Technicians ON Incidents.TechID = Technicians.TechID " +
```

to this

```
"LEFT JOIN Technicians ON Incidents.TechID = Technicians.TechID " +
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use  inner join like below :

```
"inner join Technicians ON Incidents.TechID = Technicians.TechID "
```

final query

```
 string selectStatement =
        "SELECT ProductCode, DateOpened, Customers.Name AS CustName, " + 
        "Technicians.Name as TechName, Title, DateClosed " +
        "FROM Incidents " +
        "inner JOIN Customers ON Incidents.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID " +
        "inner JOIN Technicians ON Incidents.TechID = Technicians.TechID " +
        "WHERE DateClosed IS NULL " +
        "ORDER BY DateOpened";
```